# Interval to the integral $y=f(x)=\int e^{\frac{x}{2}}\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x\right)$ when $x\leq 0$

Tags: integration

Problem: Is the area bounded by the curve $y=f(x)=\int e^{\frac{x}{2}}\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x\right)$ and the x-axis finite when $x\leq 0$?

Solution:
$\displaystyle \int_{-\frac{2}{\sqrt 3}k\pi}^{\frac{2}{\sqrt 3}(-k+1)\pi}e^{\frac{x}{2}}\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x\right)dx = ...$

I can't really understand how do they get the interval to this integral. I know that x has to be $0 \leq \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}x \leq 1$ (in this case $-1 \leq -\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}x \leq 0$), so the $-\frac{2}{\sqrt 3}k\pi$ makes sense but I don't get the $\frac{2}{\sqrt 3}(-k+1)\pi$ part. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the curve $y=f(x)=\int e^{\frac{x}{2}}\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x\right)dx$ or $y=f(x)=e^{\frac{x}{2}}\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x\right)$?

Comment: It's without the dx, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question asks for the AREA bounded by the curve, what we are really trying to find is $$\lim_{n\rightarrow-\infty}\int_{n}^0\left|e^{x/2}\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x\right)\right|dx$$

However, we can't evaluate this straight off, there is no primitive for this, so what we do is split it into a series of integrals of when $f(x)=e^{x/2}\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x\right)$ is positive and when it is negative.

We know that $e^{x/2}$ is always positive but that $\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x\right)$ is negative in the $3$rd and $4$th quadrants and positive in the $1$st and $2$nd. So to find the values of $x$ which give $\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x\right)≤0$, we solve $ \sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x\right)=0$. This gives $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x=k\pi$ or $x=-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}k\pi$ since we're working in the negative domain. Since one rotation by $\pi$ will change the domain from positive to negative, we know that the integral $$A_k=\int_{-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}k\pi}^{\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}(-k+1)\pi}e^{x/2}\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x\right)dx$$

is always positive OR negative, depending on which integer values we pick for $k$.

Therefore, to find the area we need, run through all integer values of $k$, taking the absolute value so that the negative ones become positive to represent area.

Evaluating $A_k$ (use integration by parts) gives $$|A_k|=\left|\frac{1}{2}\left(e^{\frac{-k\pi}{\sqrt{3}}}+e^{\frac{(1-k)\pi}{\sqrt{3}}}\right)(\sqrt{3}\cos{k\pi})\right|=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\left(e^{\frac{-k\pi}{\sqrt{3}}}+e^{\frac{(1-k)\pi}{\sqrt{3}}}\right)$$

Therefore the area will be $$|A_0|+|A_1|+|A_2|+|A_3|+...=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\left(e^{\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}}}\right)+\sqrt{3}\left(1+e^{-\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}}}+e^{-\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{3}}}+...\right)$$

This is clearly an infinite geometric series with a bounded sum since the common ratio is $r=e^{-\pi/\sqrt{3}}<1$.

$\therefore$ the area under $f(x)$ for $x≤0$ is finite.